# How to select/click radio button using Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am testing some actions using Selenium, and want to choose a `"banana"`. But I can't select any button. What I did wrong?

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='radio'][value='1']"))).click()
```

HTML-code
@Nithin Tata, @Mike67, @Jortega

```
<div class="st-mb__14">
<label class="st-input__title block required" for="NewForm_type_fruit">Type of fruits</label> <input id="Type_fruit" type="hidden" value="" name="NewForm[type_user]" />
<span id="NewForm_type_fruit">
    <input class="st-input" id="NewForm_type_fruit_0" value="1" type="radio" name="NewForm_type_fruit[type_fruit]" /> <label for="NewForm_type_fruit_0">banana</label><br />
    <input class="st-input" id="NewForm_type_fruit_1" value="3" type="radio" name="NewForm_type_fruit[type_fruit]" /> <label for="NewForm_type_fruit_1">orange</label><br />
    <input class="st-input" id="NewForm_type_fruit_2" value="2" type="radio" name="NewForm_type_fruit[type_fruit]" /> <label for="NewForm_type_fruit_2">pineapple</label>
</span>
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the html  as text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I created a test html file:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="x"/>banana</br>
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="x"/>orange</br>
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="x"/>pineapple</br>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

url = "file:///D:/Python/Test/banana.htm"
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
    "input[type='radio'][value='1']"))).click()
```

The checkbox works correctly:

[image: choice]

If you can provide some html (in text) that does not work, that may help us test.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I provided HTML as text first post

Comment: I tried the html you provided. The radio button still works. Are there other radio buttons on the page?

Comment: There are only three buttons on the page as the HTML. I think may be trouble in Ajax and JavaScript? But radio didn’t select as my code or yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.By.XPATH, 
//label[contains(text(),"banana")]/preceding-sibling::input))).click()
```

if this doesn't work provide HTML as text.

Comment: it doesn't work. I provided with HTML as text first post